# MultiLine Graph in CorePlot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, core-plot

I want to Draw multiple line Graph with each line have different color and different Data in Graph.

I show "CPTTestApp-iPad" an Example from Core plot 1.0 Examples folder. I plot single line chat but Still i dont clear all the thing.

Please can any one guide me to How to developing multi line chart? Any learning tutorial for multi line chart graph and beginner of core plot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Core Plot graph can have as many plots as you want and they can be different types, too. Assign a unique `identifier` to each plot and use that in your datasource to determine what values to return.

Comment: Please Can you Describe me in more Detail? I know that will be done in core plot but how can i will do that bcoz of i started learning core plote just today

Comment: Look through the example apps provided with Core Plot—many of them have more than one plot in a single graph. If you have specific questions after reviewing the examples, ask them here in a new question.